# I found duplicate rows in SQL for a one-to-(zero or one) Entity Framework relationship - How / Why?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, duplicates

I am trying to figure out how to fix some contention issues that are resulting in duplicate rows in SQL.  Below I show the code, and at the very bottom, my questions/concerns.

A full download of the VS2012 solution is available here: http://www15.zippyshare.com/d/72956037/4552733/EFConcurrency.zip

I have created an Entity Framework model using the Designer.  Here is the model:

[image]

I have populated the database with this code:

```
        using (EfTestContainer db = new EfTestContainer())
        {
            User u = new User();
            u.Email = "test@test.com";
            db.Users.Add(u);
            for (int i = 1; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                Car c = new Car();
                c.CarName = "Cool Car";
                c.User = u;
                db.Cars.Add(c);
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

As you can see, our database now has 1 user and 10,000 cars.

I then create three threads that contend with each other to add SpareTires.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // This will start three threads that all try to add SpareTires at the same time.
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(Go), new object());

    }
    public static void Go(object o)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(AddSpareTires2), new object());
        Thread.Sleep(50);
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(AddSpareTires3), new object());
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(AddSpareTires1), new object());
        while (true)
        {
            if (done1 && done2 && done3) break;
            Thread.Sleep(250);
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Done!");

    }
    public static bool done1 = false;
    public static bool done2 = false;
    public static bool done3 = false;
    private static void AddSpareTires1(object o)
    {
        using (EfTestContainer db = new EfTestContainer())
        {
            User u = db.Users.FirstOrDefault();
            var cars = db.Cars.ToList<Car>();
            foreach (var car in cars)
            {
                SpareTire st = new SpareTire();
                st.BrandName = "Cool Tire";
                car.SpareTire = st;
            }
            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (OptimisticConcurrencyException exc)
            {
                var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext;
                objectContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, cars); // It doesn't seem to make a difference if I use RefreshMode.ClientWins
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
            done1 = true;
        }
    }
    private static void AddSpareTires2(object o)
    {
        using (EfTestContainer db = new EfTestContainer())
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
            {
                int min = (i-1) * 10;
                int max = i * 10;
                User u = db.Users.FirstOrDefault();
                var cars = db.Cars.Where(c => c.Id > min && c.Id < max).ToList<Car>();
                foreach (var car in cars)
                {
                    SpareTire st = new SpareTire();
                    st.BrandName = "Cool Tire";
                    car.SpareTire = st;

                }
                try
                {
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (OptimisticConcurrencyException exc)
                {
                    var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext;
                    objectContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, cars); // It doesn't seem to make a difference if I use RefreshMode.ClientWins
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                }
            }
            done2 = true;

        }
    }
    private static void AddSpareTires3(object o)
    {
        using (EfTestContainer db = new EfTestContainer())
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
            {
                int min = (i - 1) * 100;
                int max = i * 100;
                User u = db.Users.FirstOrDefault();
                var cars = db.Cars.Where(c => c.Id > min && c.Id < max).ToList<Car>();
                foreach (var car in cars)
                {
                    SpareTire st = new SpareTire();
                    st.BrandName = "Cool Tire";
                    car.SpareTire = st;
                }
                try
                {
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (OptimisticConcurrencyException exc)
                {
                    var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext;
                    objectContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, cars); // It doesn't seem to make a difference if I use RefreshMode.ClientWins
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                }
            }
            done3 = true;
        }
    }
```

The result is that there are 1 User, 10,000 Cars, and 10,899 SpareTires!

1. Why did SQL/EF allow the Car / SpareTire 1 to (zero or 1) relationship to be violated?
2. How do I fix my code so that, after running, only 1 User, 10,000 Cars, and 10,000 SpareTires exist?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Note: I filed an issue in CodePlex for the EF team to check whether this is actually a bug: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1468

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a one-to-one relationship with **Model-First** Entity Framework maps it actually to a one-to-many relationship on database side. You can see that when opening the edmx file in an xml editor (you can also find it in the `.Store` section of the designer's model browser). In the `<edmx:StorageModels>` section you'll find:

```
<Association Name="CarSpareTire">
  <End Role="Car" Type="EfTest.Store.Cars" Multiplicity="1" />
  <End Role="SpareTire" Type="EfTest.Store.SpareTires" Multiplicity="*" />
  <ReferentialConstraint>
    <Principal Role="Car">
      <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
    </Principal>
    <Dependent Role="SpareTire">
      <PropertyRef Name="Car_Id" />
    </Dependent>
  </ReferentialConstraint>
</Association>
```

The multiplicity is `*` on one side and the foreign key is a separate key `Car_Id` that is a database column but not a property in your model. In the `<edmx:ConceptualModels>` section the association is defined as one-to-zero..one:

```
<Association Name="CarSpareTire">
  <End Type="EfTest.Car" Role="Car" Multiplicity="1" />
  <End Type="EfTest.SpareTire" Role="SpareTire" Multiplicity="0..1" />
</Association>
```

As a result the database has no knowledge about a one-to-one relationship and will allow to store multiple `SpareTire`s (with the same `Car_Id` value) for a single `Car` (*as if* the `Car` actually had a `SpareTires` *collection* and not a single reference).

I have no clue why EF does map the relationship this way to the database and if it's intended or a bug. But in your multithreaded scenario it can't work and you will get those multiple `SpareTire`s per `Car` in the database (which is wrong according to the conceptual model).

I see three options to fix the problem:

- Use Code-First instead of Model-First. Code-First maps one-to-zero..one relationships (one side optional, the other side required) to real one-to-zero..one relationships in the database using shared primary keys, i.e. there will be no `Car_Id` column but the primary key in `SpareTire` is the foreign key to `Car` at the same time. With shared primary keys the database can't store multiple dependents for the same principal and your problem cannot occur.
- Follow [this approach](http://www.develop-one.net/blog/2011/06/29/EntityFrameworkModelFirstOnetoOneRelationship.aspx) to create a one-to-zero..one relationship with shared primary keys with Model-First. It actually seems to be possible with Model-First but it is not the default.
- Add a unique constraint to the `Car_Id` column (manually in the database or in the SQL script that Model-First creates)

In all cases you will get exceptions from the database when two threads try to insert a `SpareTire` for the same `Car`. I am not sure if `OptimisticConcurrencyException`s. They could also be other exception types indicating duplicate primary keys, so you might put something into your empty `catch (Exception) { }` blocks to notify you at least when they are entered.